# matmul to every row in pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I currently have a tensor that looks like this (numbers randomly selected), which I will call x:

```
tensor([[ 1., -5.],
        [ 2., -4.],
        [ 3.,  2.],
        [ 4.,  1.],
        [ 5.,  2.]])
```

I also have another 2D tensor (call it i)

```
tensor([[-1.,  1.],
        [ 1., -1.]], requires_grad=True)
```

I hope to **pytorch.matmul** i to each row in x. Is there a way for me to achieve this?

Below is my attempt:

```
apply_i = lambda x: torch.matmul(x, i)
final = pytorch.tensor([apply_i(a) for a in x])
```

It throws an error saying *"only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars"*. Does not work even when I remove the square bracket.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([[ 1., -5.],
        [ 2., -4.],
        [ 3.,  2.],
        [ 4.,  1.],
        [ 5.,  2.]])
```

change your code:

```
i = torch.tensor([[-1.,  1.],
        [ 1., -1.]], requires_grad=True)
apply_i = lambda x: torch.matmul(x, i)
# final = torch.tensor([apply_i(a) for a in x])
final = [apply_i(a) for a in x]
final = torch. stack(final)
```